# How deploy geoserver web archive with apache tomcat 8?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat8, webarchive

I want to run geoserver `web archive` in my `tomcat` web server. I'm using tomcat 8.
I download GeoServer 2.7.1.1 `web archive` from [geoserver](http://geoserver.org). When I want to deploy the war file, Error occurs as follow:
[image]

But when I deploy another `war` application, it deployed correctly.

Where is problem?

Comment: is there something useful in your tomcat server's manager log file ?

Comment: there is not loging in log files

Comment: running into the same problem.. any updates?

Comment: anybody found a solution to this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because, *Tomcat WebServer* has a size limit of **50 mb**  **max** which is smaller than *Geoserver war* file. All you need to do is to modify

> DIR\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml

and modify the following lines:

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 52MB max -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Just set the size as follow (520 mb in my case or whatever value you want.)

```
<max-file-size>524288000</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>524288000</max-request-size>
```

Hope it solves your problem.